# My rendered image is still showing black after applying alpha clip and using an alpha

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, materials, shaders, transparency

I'm using cycles and trying to get the background areas that don't have any texture to be transparent. Here's my shading nodes and the rendered view, along with the texture tab open on the side. Any suggestions?[image]

Comment: What are you trying to get by connecting as volume?

Comment: I was actually following a tutorial, I think that may have been the way you got rid of the black stuff in older versions of blender?

Answer (score 1):

Remove everything except the image node and the output node. Add a principled BSDF node in between. Connect the color output of your image to the base color input of the principled BSDF shader. Connect the alpha output of your Image to the alpha input of the principled BSDF shader. Connect the principled BSDF output to the surface input of material output node.

[image: Nodes]

Comment: Thanks! That worked great. I'll play around and see if I can still get the same effects, but so far this is better than nothing