# Rendered texture is still black after connecting alpha channel to BSDF

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders, texture-painting

I've created a texture that is just a pure black square on a plane, and I connected the alpha channel to the alpha input on Principled BSDF like this answer suggests: [My rendered image is still showing black after applying alpha clip and using an alpha](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/194060/my-rendered-image-is-still-showing-black-after-applying-alpha-clip-and-using-an)

However, the rendered image is still black (except for the red line I drew on it). What am I doing wrong?
[image: shading node graph]

Comment: Hard to say from given info. I suppose you checked UVmap that is correct. How looks your texture (you described, but not totally clear for me. What is the left yellow line? ... if no one - share your file, delete all except the issued object https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: Texture image is literally a black square. The UV map is correct as I can texture draw on the plane. Left yellow line is just other parts of my scene. Only the black square is relevant to my question

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue -- the black is NOT corresponding with 0 alpha, it is a black RGB value. To get transparency I needed to select the Erase Alpha paint mode on my texture.
[image: erase alpha mode]

Comment: sure ... if you plan use the black as alpha you have to plug Texture's Color socket to BSDF's Alpha socket.